# Extracting unordered list for a particular <div>: BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping this [webpage](http://www.howtocallabroad.com/a.html) needed for my android app. What I would like to do is to extract the countries from `href` attribute.  This is the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267768/beautiful-soup-extracting-href-from-html-ordered-list).

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.howtocallabroad.com/a.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
li = soup.select("ul > li > a")
for link in li:
    print link.get('href')
```

The problem i'm getting is that the result returns all `a` tag including from other `div`s

```
afghanistan/
albania/
algeria/
american-samoa/
andorra/
angola/
anguilla/
antigua/
argentina/
armenia/
aruba/
ascension/
australia/
austria/
azerbaijan/
codes.html  # not needed
nanp.html   # not needed
qa/         # not needed
forums/     # not needed
```

I'd like to know on what function/s needed to accomplish this. I want to filter `href`s in `<div id="content">` only. The [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) doesnt have much info.

Sorry this is the first time i write python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `findAll()`:

```
>>> for i in soup.find('div',{'id':'content'}).findAll('a'):
...     print i['href']
... 
afghanistan/
albania/
algeria/
american-samoa/
andorra/
angola/
anguilla/
antigua/
argentina/
armenia/
aruba/
ascension/
australia/
austria/
azerbaijan/
```

`soup.find('div',{'id':'content'})` Does what it says. It finds the div tag which has an `id` of `content` (`<div id="content">` would be matched).

`.findAll()`... finds all! `'a'` is used as a parameter to find all the a tags. It returns a list of each a tag.

Then I simply print each a-tag's `href`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
li = soup.select("#content ul > li > a")
```

instead of

```
li = soup.select("ul > li > a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
li = soup.select("#content ul > li > a")
```

For example:

```
li = soup.select("#[call india][1] ul > li > a")
```