# Python Selenium - Extract all URL's In Table and iterate until next button disappears

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract all URL's and iterate where the next button is pressed until there isn't a next button. I would then like to open each URL if that is possible. Could I be pointed in the right direction for this please.

The website where you need to press the search button is [here](http://from%20selenium%20import%20webdriver%20from%20selenium.webdriver.common.by%20import%20By%20%20driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r%22C:%5CUsers%5Cmatt_%5CDocuments%5CPython%20Scripts%5CSelenium%5Cchromedriver.exe%22)%20%20%20driver.get(%22https://publicaccess.aberdeencity.gov.uk/online-applications/search.do?action=monthlyList%22)%20driver.find_element_by_xpath(%22/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/div[5]/input[2]%22).click()%20test%20=%20driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,%22a%22)%20%20%20print(test))

Link to [Table of URL's that need to be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmRym.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\matt_\Documents\Python Scripts\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")


driver.get("https://publicaccess.aberdeencity.gov.uk/online-applications/search.do?action=monthlyList")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/div[5]/input[2]").click()
test = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")


print(test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the element exists or not with simple logic like this:

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.next')) > 0:
```

Try the below code:

```
driver.get('https://publicaccess.aberdeencity.gov.uk/online-applications/search.do?action=monthlyList')
search_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.button.primary')))
search_btn.click()

condition = True
while condition:
    links = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.searchresult a')))
    for link in links:
        print(link.get_attribute('href'))

    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.next')) > 0:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.next').click()
    else:
        condition = False

driver.quit()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example what you looking for

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd 
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://monerobenchmarks.info/")

page = Soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')

final_list = []

def parsh_table():
    table = page.find('table')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        final_list.extend(row)

def next_bu():
    next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cpu_next"]')
    next_button.click()

# put range of pages
for _ in range(1,2):
    parsh_table()
    time.sleep(2)
    next_bu()


print(final_list)
```

Comment: Would this be considered a table? <ul id="searchresults"> == $0

Comment: yes just change Next_button xpath and the link in driver.get('YOUR_WEBSITE_URL')

Comment: also change parser_table() function this link might help. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915856/extracting-unordered-list-for-a-particular-div-beautifulsoup`

Comment: Could you have a go when you press the search button please. I have been trying to do this but haven't got any further

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\matt_\Documents\Python Scripts\Selenium\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://publicaccess.aberdeencity.gov.uk/online-applications/search.do?action=monthlyList")

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Search']").click()

    def parse():
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchresults"]/li/a')
        for link in links:
            print(link.text, link.get_attribute("href"))
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('next').click()
            parse()
        except:
            print('complete')

    parse()
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and made the same indentations but it is not returning anything after I run. It gets to the correct page but does not iterate through next nor return any URL's. I appreciate the help so far @Dmitry :)

Comment: Maybe I’m not quite understand your question, but it prints each url on each page until last page is reached, if you want to return list of urls just define list variable and add them to it. If I’m wrong correct me please.

Comment: Its just not returning anything. The idea was correct. Sorry for not making clear